# resetting index based on list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to reset the index based on a list

Lets say i have dataframe like this

```
 list = ['RGB','RBR','RGD']

       a   b

RBR    0   1 
RGD    10  2  
RGB    11  3  
RGD    10  2 
RGD    10  2  
RGD    10  2  
RBR    0   1  
RGB    11  3
```

df.reindex(index=list)

> File
>   "c:\users\yugas\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3560, in _can_reindex
>       raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
>
> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Any other way i can do this?

Comment: Side note: don't name variables after classes, e.g. use `lst` or `L` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not reindex just use `.loc` i.e

```
li =  ['RGB','RBR','RGD']
df = df.loc[li]

    a  b
RGB  11  3
RGB  11  3
RBR   0  1
RBR   0  1
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate values in your index. `pd.DataFrame.reindex` requires your index to be unique.

One efficient solution available to Pandas is [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), taking care to specify `ordered=True`.

```
L = ['RGB', 'RBR', 'RGD']

df.index = pd.Categorical(df.index, categories=L, ordered=True)

res = df.sort_index()

print(res)

      a  b
RGB  11  3
RGB  11  3
RBR   0  1
RBR   0  1
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
RGD  10  2
```